# Upload only new files to google drive leaving already uploaded files using Python?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

Here is my code
suggestions with my below code to upload only new files  to google drive leaving already uploaded files using Python ??

I want to upload files whenever a new files comes to a folder then to google drive

```
import os
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
gauth = GoogleAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
folder = '1aoonhCebvI5DddvJVGTzBvWs2BPn_yXN'
directory = "/Volumes/g2track/Shared/Egnyte Audit Reports/2022/Abhi"
for f in os.listdir(directory):
    filename=os.path.join(directory, f)
    gfile = drive.CreateFile({'parents' : [{'id' : folder}],'title' : f})
    gfile.SetContentFile(filename )
    gfile.Upload()
```

Comment: You seem to be missing code that checks if a file already exists (is uploaded)

Comment: Hey, can you please help with that alteration in the code? It will be very helpful @OneCricketeer

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `pydrive` API. Last I checked, [that library is deprecated](https://github.com/googlearchive/PyDrive#deprecated) anyway. If you use PyDrive2, then you can list the contents of a folder to check what exists before you upload things - https://github.com/iterative/PyDrive2#file-listing-pagination-made-easy